# Fit a column in expanded or container widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using innerDrawer in my profilePage. I put a column in scaffold and added widgets inside. One of these widgets is SignedContracts and this widget has an Expanded widget with a column inside. I want to fit or fill this column in expanded or container widget like second picture. I try lots of things but I did not find any solution.

Note: The red borders in the first picture to see the borders of the containers.

I made this:
[image: I made this]

But I want like this:
[image: But I want like this]

Scaffold part:

```
scaffold: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                ),
                child: Image.network(
                  "${firestoreDB.user.photoURL}",
                  width: 500,
                  height: 250,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _toggle();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Text(
                  "${_user.name}",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                bottom: 50,
                left: 50,
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Text(
                  "${_user.desc}",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
                bottom: 30,
                left: 50,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          MiddleCounts(lastWeekListen, lastWeekStream,sL),
          Row(),
          SignedContracts(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

SignedContracts widget:

```
class SignedContracts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        //height: 500,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        //color: Colors.black,
        child: Container(
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
          child: Column(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Signed Contracts",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Multiple Rights Agreement",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Sound Recording Licence",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Merchandising Agreement",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Synchronisation Licence",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Artist Development Agreement",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Management Agreement",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "Manage Contracts",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your second Column in SignedContracts class with `Expanded` widget like code below:

```
class SignedContracts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        //height: 500,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        //color: Colors.black,
        child: Container(
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
          child: Column(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Signed Contracts",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Multiple Rights Agreement",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Sound Recording Licence",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Merchandising Agreement",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Synchronisation Licence",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Artist Development Agreement",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Management Agreement",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "Manage Contracts",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```